# Understanding Chapter 2 Q 22 of A Little Java, A Few Patterns

Tags: java, design-patterns

In Chapter 2 of *A Little Java, A Few Patterns*, Question 22 is:

> Are there only Onions on this Shish^D:
>
> **new** Skewer()?

Answer is:

> true, because there is neither Lamb nor Tomato on **new** Skewer().

[definitions of classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZuyv.png)

Skewer is a subclass of Shish^D, Onion is also a subclass of Shish^D, I don't understand why there are onions on `new Skewer()`, could someone explain this a bit further?

Comment: This is not the `homework helpline`

Comment: I feel like there's more information to be shared here apart from that picture.  This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I feel like there is something missing here, because "true" is not an answer to a question starting "Are there...".

Comment: Sincerely, Onion inheriting from Skewer inheriting from Shish^D? WTF of book on Java is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've googled the book and although some pages are missing, I think this is what the question's about:

```
Shish s = new Skewer();
System.out.println(s.onlyOnions()); //prints true;
```

It prints true because `onlyOnions()` is declared `abstract` in the super class `Shish` and overriden in the `Skewer` class as follows:

```
class Skewer extends Shish {
      @Override
      boolean onlyOnions(){
        return true;
      }
}
```

So it should be clear that `s.onlyOnions()` returns true, since s' dynamic type is `Skewer`.

Comment: Just found this on the next page. I'm confused by the structure of this book. Thanks a lot.